# ssh command in background

Tags: ssh, background-process, csh

Please help in following.

I am doing `ssh user@server "source script.csh"` from my home server

Let us suppose `script.csh` contains 10 commands :

- 1st to 3rd command runs instantaneously
- 4th command takes 10-12 hours to complete
- 5th to 10th command also runs instantaneously
- Last command copies the data back to home server.

I do want to hold to the shell of remote server for 10-12 hours. Also I want commands to run in the sequentially. I will keep monitoring for the files to come back on the home server to know the completion of my script on remote server.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `screen` in order to run something in the background so that you can close the SSH connection. I am not familiar with `csh` but the call would look like this:

```
ssh user@server "screen -S longrunscript csh -c 'source script.csh'"
```

The `-S longrunscript` gives the screen session a name so that you can easily attach to it (even if there are other screen sessions around) using `screen -x longrunscript`.

Comment: (`-x` implies `-r` (: )

Comment: @DopeGhoti You wouldn't expect it from reading the man page but it seems you are correct.

Comment: The main difference is that `-x` will attach to a screen session even if it's already attached elsewhere (which allows for multiuser screen sessions).  Since it's a superset of `-r`, I just use it whenever I'm reconnecting to a screen session.

Comment: I can't use screen. Is there any other solution ??

Comment: @SaurabhVarshney `nohup command &`